# Erlang Pattern Matching Order

Tags: recursion, erlang, pattern-matching

I wrote a simple function in Erlang which converts a tuple to list. But I don't understand why pattern matching order matters here :

**Example**

```
tupleToList(Tuple) -> tupleToList(Tuple, size(Tuple), []).
tupleToList(_, 0, L) -> L;
tupleToList(Tuple, S, L) -> tupleToList(Tuple, S - 1, [element(S, Tuple) | L]).
```

Why is the following code not correct?

```
tupleToList(Tuple) -> tupleToList(Tuple, size(Tuple), []).
tupleToList(Tuple, S, L) -> tupleToList(Tuple, S - 1, [element(S, Tuple) | L]);
tupleToList(_, 0, L) -> L.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [that's how functions work in Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions.html#function-evaluation):

> If the function is found, the function clauses are scanned **sequentially** until a clause is found that fulfills both of the following two conditions:
>
> - The patterns in the clause head can be successfully matched against the given arguments.
> - The guard sequence, if any, is true.

Since variables match everything, and there's no guard sequence, the `tupleToList(Tuple, S, L)` clause is always chosen in the second case, before the `tupleToList(_, 0, L)` is ever considered.

Comment: Thanks. Understood my mistake here. tupleToList(Tuple, S, L) matches (Tuple,0,L) that's why second pattern is unreachable.